# NodeJs async sql to variable

Tags: node.js, sqlite, asynchronous

I want a result like this 
`var rolecheck = ['289773584216358912','281531832938266625'];`

Only fetched from a database, so I can compare it to another array with Id's (and yes it's supposed to be a string)

The purpoose of this is to check, before executing a command, if the user has a specific role with permission for that role. So it needs to be a function able to be called.

I've never worked with NodeJs async functions, so i have no clue how to convert this sql to an array:

The content of the .then is just some code of me trying to find out how it works, so ignore the consolelogs etc. Note: the logs do return the correct roles, but i just need them to return them to use them in my compare function.

```
sql.all("SELECT roleId FROM roles WHERE punish = 'true' and guildId = '"+guildids+"'").then(row => {
        if (row) {
            var rolecheck = [];
            row.forEach(function(row){
                rolecheck.push(row.roleId);
            });
            console.log(rolecheck);
        }
    });
```

returning does not work, so I need a workaround.

Here's where i compare it: (this works fine as long as rolecheck and role.id are defined correctly, which they aren't. It does work when i hardcode the rolecheck array.

```
member.forEach(function(role){
  if(HasRole(rolecheck, role.id)){
      console.log('user has role: '+role.name);
      return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is async. You can't return from `.then` handler because the context of the outer function no longer exists at the time when `.then` fires. You have to do your check **inside** the `.then` handler. In other words your code has to be written in a nested manner.

Comment: i was afraid of that. Isn't there an alternative for .then?

Comment: Well, you don't really have to do things in "nested" manner. You can always chain `.then()` calls assuming your previous `.then()` returns a promise object. But that totally depends on how this `sql` object is implemented.

Comment: I've been digging a little bit and came across Callback. Do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you can use a node version with async/await support, like version 7, here is a way to write promise-based code in a synchronous manner. This makes it simpler to pass around the row value.

```
async function myFunction () {
  try {
    let member = ''; // whatever member should be

    let row = await sql.all("SELECT roleId FROM roles WHERE punish = 'true' and guildId = '"+guildids+"'");

    // now you have the row available, outside of 'then' blocks

    var rolecheck = [];

    if (row) {
      row.forEach(function(row){
        rolecheck.push(row.roleId);
      });
      console.log(rolecheck);
    }

    member.forEach(function(role){
      if (HasRole(rolecheck, role.id)) {
        console.log('user has role: '+role.name);
        return true;
      }
    });

  } catch (error) {
    consol.log(error.stack);
  }
}
```

If sql.all did not return a promise you could instead do something like this which would also work with callback based functions

```
async function myFunction () {
  try {

    let row = await runSql();

    // everything else same as first example above
}

async function runSql () {
  try {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      sql.all("SELECT roleId FROM roles WHERE punish = 'true' and guildId = '"+guildids+"'")
      .then(row => {
        if (row) {
          var rolecheck = [];
          row.forEach(function(row){
              rolecheck.push(row.roleId);
          });
          console.log(rolecheck);
          resolve(row);
        } else {
          reject('Row not found');
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('erro')
  }
};
```